# NodeJS - Storing command line output as a var and returning it to client via res.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, exec, stdout

I am currently working on the back end of an application, using NodeJS. As part of my code, I read the first line of a file and send that to a client using res.json. My code looks like this

```
var hr = 'head -n 1 ../' + req.file.path + '_hr.txt';

exec(hr, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(hr);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    res.json({
      "heartrate": stdout
    }); 

})
```

When I execute this however, I get

```
{"heartrate" : ""}
```

even though on the console of the back end I see a value for stdout.

I have looked at other related questions but the information I've got has been in bits and pieces. I realise the object produced by stdout is not a string. I tried the toString() method on it but that didn't work.

I also put an if(stdout) around the res.json since exec is ansynchronous and may stdout may not have been written to at the point when I call console.log(stdout), but that also did not work.

I also tried using spawn instead of exec to no avail, although I may have used it wrongly. I'm sure the solution to my problem is very simple, but I have not been able to find it. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try storing it in a variable first `var output = stdout.toString()`, then console.logging the `output` variable, and then sending it?

Comment: [btw I tried it (different command) and it works](http://i.imgur.com/OYiYzCN.png)

Comment: Tried that, logging the output variable showed blank as well

Comment: Oh that's really weird, could it possibly have something to do with my command then?

Comment: Could be, but you said that `console.log(stdout)` shows the correct output?

Comment: Yeah. Can you try executing the exec within an app.post() to see if it works the same?

Comment: I imagine it would work the same. Can you post how you're using it? Like how you're requesting it on the client-side and how that request is handled on server. posting full code would be ideal

Comment: [link] (http://imgur.com/a/dpQaY) - This is the back java script on the back end. Someone else is working on the client side, but it's basically a http post request. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: hmm, can't spot anything odd. Did the `res.send()` work? Does `res.json({some:"thing else"})` work?

Comment: res.send(stdout) didn't work either. Both work if passed a string, but not stdout. I'm gonna work around this and send the result back as a file instead, since I'm constrained for time. But thanks a lot!

Comment: Turns out I was logging the wrong exec, miscommunication between myself and the person who wrote the python script. Thanks for the help again

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was logging the wrong stdout, logged the right one and got the answer I wanted